# What is the difference between Earth Science and Sustainable Living SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

Can anybody clarify what is the main differences between [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) and [Sustainable Living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange sites?
As I'm finding it a bit confusing where to ask and what kind of questions.

Both seems to be related to planet Earth and the environment.

How do I distinguish which question is the right to which site?

E.g. which site is the right to ask the questions about protecting Earth, rainforest, substitute of wood, seawater pollution or [EPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Environmental_Protection_Agency) questions?

Answer (score 12):

Earth Science focuses on scientific questions: What effects does deforestation of the Amazon have on regional precipitation patterns?  What greenhouse gases are emitted by hydro-power lakes in midlatitude mountain regions?  How has replacing CFCs with FCFCs impacted stratospheric chemistry?

Sustainable Living focuses more on technology and personal choices.  How can I tell what kind of wood to buy if I want to make sure it is sustainable?  If I choose a Green Energy package in {country}, will it include biomass and hydro power even if those have some bad impacts?  What kind of fridge might I buy if I want that it has no CFCs and no FCFCs?

Then there are questions related to policy.  How does the London congestion charge affect urban air quality?  How are emission targets enforced?  Etc.  This category is harder to place.  Some fit here.  Some on Sustainable Living.  Some on Politics.  Some on Economics.  Perhaps some fit on two or three or four of those sites.  I would judge it on a case-by-case basis.  We can always migrate questions if the community thinks a question fits better elsewhere.

Answer (score 6):

Gerrit's given you a great answer already. Let me add a bit, as a mod on [Sustainable Living, aka Sustainability.SE](http://Sustainability.stackexchange.com/).

Both sites cover the science of sustainability as it relates to systems and processes in nature: climate change, pollution, natural resources.

Earth Science also covers all of Earth's (and other planets') other natural processes: volcanoes, deep-ocean currents, river formation, glacier movement, and so on. Sustainable Living does not cover these.

Sustainability.SE covers those bits of the natural environment *that intersect with human activities in some way*, and most of those would be off-topic here on Earth Science - e.g. [gardening](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gardening), [industrial production](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/industrial-production) and [city living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city-living)

Here are some examples.

#### Off-topic here, on-topic at Sustainability.SE

- [How long does it take to construct a new port suitable for offshore wind construction?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/2393/48)
- [How can electricity grids successfully incorporate high (50%+) penetrations of PV and wind?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/1282/48)
- [Biodegradable cleaners to remove mold?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/61/48)

#### On-topic at either site

- [To stop anthropogenic climate change, is it necessary to stop extracting petroleum and start pumping carbon under ground?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/2753/100)
- [Academic but accessible defense of the scientific understanding of anthropogenic climate change?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/2683/100)
- [To what extent is hydroelectric power really renewable?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/2425/100)

#### On-topic here, off-topic at Sustainability.SE

- [Is it possible for rivers to freeze completely and stop flowing?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/4358/100)
- [What is the origin of the Laacher See caldera magma in Germany?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/4387/100)
- [Earthquake probabilities](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/4357/100)